# How can I access my Windows partition as an ordinary user?

Tags: permissions, automount

I have a dual boot laptop with Win7  and Ubuntu 11.10.
Since few days my Ubuntu does not mount automatically the win partition or a usb drive. It's also not possible to change the desktop wallpaper.

I "fixed" the win partition by hand modifying `/etc/fstab`. I also played a bit and now Ubuntu mount the usb drive. On the other hand I cannot unmount them because

```
umount: only root can unmount UUID=521832F21832D4A7 from /media/WINDOWS
```

But my account is admin, so I do not understand why I have this message.
If I unmount with sudo from terminal there is no problem.
For the wallpaper I have no error message but I can't change anything.
I also tried to assign my account to "normal" user group and then back to admin group: useless.

I believe that even if my account is administrator there is something messed up with permissions. Few days ago a guest played a bit with my account and the standard guest user (he couldn't unlock as he forgot the password). I don't know if this could be the cause, but at the moment I don't understand what it could be.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `sudo` command in the Terminal, that causes what you type after `sudo` to be run as root. This is why it works from the Terminal--because the technique you are using makes you act as root.

Being an administrator does not mean you are `root`, or that most of what you do is done as root. It does mean that you can perform actions as root with a couple of built-in facilities (one of which is `sudo`).

When partitions are mounted automatically from `/etc/fstab`, the mount operation is performed by `root`, so it is necessary to be `root` (or run a command as `root`) to undo it. This is the normal and expected behavior, and not a bug.

When you mount partitions dynamically as a non-`root` user, behind the scenes, that uses `udisks --mount`. Then you can unmount them automatically with `udisks --unmount` (which is what happens behind the scenes when you unmount them). The way you fixed your problem prevents this from happening, because `/etc/fstab` entries are not mounted/unmounted dynamically with `udisks`.

So it seems that the way you've fixed your problem does not fully suit your needs. I recommend that you post a new question detailing the problem you were experiencing, so that someone can help you make automatic, non-`root` mounting and unmounting of your Windows partition work again.

Comment: I didn't know that fstab does its job under root (even in ubuntu where there is no root?). The udisks thing seems promising but everything worked out of the box after installation (months ago) without configuring anything. At this point I cannot use the touchpad anymore and still having the wallpaper problem. Is there a way to understand if this is a permission problem?

Comment: @ray The touchpad problem is also probably a separate problem. To address your question about there being "no root" in Ubuntu: In Ubuntu, there absolutely **is** a `root` account. It just has logins disabled. Logging in as root is not supported, recommended, or necessary, because the system provides facilities like `sudo` to allow a non-`root` user to perform actions as `root`. The root account still does exist. Run `top` in the Terminal, and you'll see plenty of programs running as `root` as part of the system. (Press `q` to quit `top`.)

Comment: It seems the touchpad is going away after trying to unmount the win partitions from nautilus. And now I noticed my terminal disappeared from the Launcher (i usually call it from a shortcut, that's why I didn't see it before!). I will follow your suggestion trying to split the problem in different questions even if their concurrent appearance hints, IMO, a common root cause.  Thank you anyway for your information